# How to get my side-bar menu to appear when I click the menu icon in my app on Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, drop-down-menu

I'm using Android Studio and a Pixel XL API 33 emulator using Kotlin. Whenever I click on my menu icon the side bar menu doesn't pop up for me. It only pops up when I click and drag my mouse from the left side of the screen from where the menu icon is located.

I want to make it so that whenever I click on the menu icon for my side-bar menu to appear not when I drag it over from the edge of the screen.

This is what I have tried:

```
private lateinit var studentDbRef: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
private lateinit var circularProfileImage : ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)


        // Hooks
        navigationView = binding.navViews
        toolbar = binding.toolbar
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        circularProfileImage = binding.circularProfileImage

        // Tool Bar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        navigationView.bringToFront()

        // Nav Bar
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.nav_drawer_open,
            R.string.nav_drawer_close
        )

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

    toolbar.navigationIcon = circularProfileImage.drawable
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener{
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```